# AppFabric - List object returned has objects with null values

Tags: wcf, list, null, appfabric

I am new to AppFabric and exploring it. I am able to put List in appfabric and able to retrieve the list using Get method. However, after retrieveing all the properties of the objects are set as null. Can anybody help how can I resolve this problem.

Following is sample code

```
//Country object 
Country country1 = new Country();
country1.Name ="test";
//Create list
List <Country> countryList = new List <Country>();
countryList.Add(country1);
//Add to AppFabric
_cache.Put("countryKey",countryList)
 //Retrieve from cache
List <Country> countryList  = (List <Country>)_cache.Get("countryKey");
//check the result
countryList.Count returns 1 which is expected.
countryList[0].Name returns null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects are stored in the cache in a serialized form. AppFabric uses the [NetDataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.netdatacontractserializer.aspx) class for serialization before storing the items in the cache.

Empty properties generally means that there is a problem in serialization/deserialization. Try to Add `DataContract` attribute   to `Country` and `DataMember` attribute to each property you want to keep this class.